# Create Numbered List of Tagged Articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, tags

Using the built-in Joomla Tags, I have several menu items that are Tags > Compact list of tagged items.

I'd like to have the list numbered on the front end- is there an easy way to do this? Possibly by numbering the table rows via CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use these CSS properties: counter-reset, counter-increment.

for instance:

```
.tag-category table {  

  counter-reset: section;
}

.tag-category table tr{
  counter-increment: section;
}

.tag-category table tr td a:before {
  content: counter(section) '. ';
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: I will try it and let you know!